# $_SESSION variables returning r

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a file where I pass the content of the database for the $_SESSION

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid' OR user_email = '$uid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
$_SESSION['u_id'] = row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['u_first'] = row['user_first'];
$_SESSION['u_last'] = row['user_last'];
$_SESSION['u_email'] = row['user_email'];
$_SESSION['u_uid'] = row['user_uid'];
header("Location: ../index.php?login=sucess");
```

In my header file I start my session with session_start() which I attach to the index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
?>

<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                echo "Bem-vindo!";
                print_r($_SESSION);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</section>

<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

and that is what happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LGTq.png)

So it seems like my array is all filled with "r" and I don't really know why, any thoughts?

Comment: curious?  Do you have a `session_start()` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to use it for every page of the website. Is it not necessary?

Comment: I just didn't see it, though I did forget that 'r' means you forgot to put a $ in front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update `$row` instead of `row`

**Example**

```
$_SESSION['u_id'] = row['user_id'];
```

replace with

```
$_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
```

For all the variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid' OR user_email = '$uid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

> ```
> session_start(); // You need to this function
> ```

```
$_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
$_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
$_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
$_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
header("Location: ../index.php?login=sucess");
```

Comment: you are missing `$` sign before `row['user_id'];` this.

Answer (score 0):

As you missed `$` for your `row` variable. It should be like as `$row['user_id']`

```
$_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
$_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
$_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
$_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
```